# boost::format and wchar_t

Tags: c++, boost, formatting, wchar-t

I am trying to format a string using boost:

```
wchar_t *msg;
// fill msg
boost::format("Error: %s") % msg).str()
```

What I get instead of msg's content, is the address of msg in hex.

No success with things like these:

```
boost::format("Error: %s") % new std::wstring(msg)
boost::format("Error: %1%") % msg
```

Note: Even though I think it's irrelevant, but the way that I fill msg is:

```
FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM | FORMAT_MESSAGE_ALLOCATE_BUFFER | 40, NULL, GetLastError(), MAKELANGID(0, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US), (LPTSTR) &msg, 512, NULL);
```

and Visual Studio Watch displays the content of msg correctly.

Comment: Why not dereference msg?

Comment: Have you tried `"%ls"`? It's used for wide-character strings.

Comment: @Ylisar dereferencing with *msg prints the ascii code of the first character

Comment: @JoachimPileborg just the same with "%1s": prints address not the content

Comment: @shayan Not digit 1, the letter _ell_, small L.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: Write an _answer_!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using `boost::wformat` to work with `wchar_t` strings.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use `boost::wformat` as suggested by wilx. Or you can change your format string to use `"%ls"` (where the `l` is the letter *ell*, small L.) This modifies the `"%s"` to expect wide character strings.

Comment: I'm afraid: %ls (with small L) prints the address. yet this one: boost::wformat(L"Error: %1%") % msg).str() prints the content